# What is the difference between x.pow(n) and pow(x, n)?

Tags: dart

I'm wondering because when I run my code in checked mode there seems to be some discrepancies. For example:

```dart
List<List> getFactors(int n) 
{
    List<List> factors = [[1, n]];
    double top = pow(n,1/2);
    int test = 2;
    while (test <= top) 
    {
        if (n % test == 0)
            factors.add([test, n ~/ test]);
        test++;
    }
    return factors;
}
```

works as is, but when I change the `pow(n,1/2)` to `n.pow(1/2)` it returns an error in checked mode. The only fix is to change the type of `n` to a double. Why is this? Also the general differences between the two would be nice to know. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think int, num, or double have a pow method, there is only Math.pow(). http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_math.html#pow http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/num.html

Comment: I know it's not listed in the api reference, but try something like `print(9.pow(2));` and it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** int/num/double.pow() currently exist only in the VM, and will be [removed](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10268). Use [math.pow()](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_math.html#pow) instead.

---

The signature for int.pow() is:

```
int pow(int exponent)
```

So the following example fails in checked mode as 1/2 does not evaluate to an integer.

```
int i = 5;
i.pow(1/2);
```

So calling int.pow() expects an integer exponent (Only checked in checked mode), and returns an integer.

And, calling math.pow(num x, num exponent), does not require an integer exponent, and may return a double, if x is an integer and exponent is a double.

Here is a link to the [math.pow()](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_math.html#pow) documentation. Here are links to the [int.pow()](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/runtime/lib/integers.dart) and [math.pow()](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/runtime/lib/math_patch.dart) source code so you can see what happens under the hood.